# Transaction propagation

Tags: transactions, transaction-propagation

I`ve got one really basic but still important question that is very confusing:
Does the newly created transaction needs to be propagated to **ALL** nodes in the network in order to be validated?
Lets suppose I have made some payment and it needs to be added to the mempool of few miners to be included in the next block. How many nodes must validate that transaction so that it will be added to the mempool?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the newly created transaction needs to be propagated to ALL
>   nodes in the network in order to be validated?

No. The nodes **relay** valid transactions to each other. In corner case you can send your transaction directly to miner node. No one will have this transaction until it included in block

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So if I understand it correctly: when node receives any transaction it will try to validate that and (if that tx is valid from the perspective of that node), that node is going to put tx in the mempool and send that tx to another neighbor node? And this proces repeats N times, basically until that tx is included in the block or all nodes have that tx in the mempool?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Note, that nodes are not obliged to relay or/and keep txs in their mempool.